# Problema com gerador de makefiles do CMake

Tags: makefile, mingw, cmake

Boas ando a seguir [este](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Building_with_msys2) tutorial de como instalar o allegro 5 com o MSYS2.

Mas tenho um problema. No momento em que vou vou correr o comando

`cmake \
    -G"MSYS Makefiles" \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/ \
    -DWANT_MONOLITH=on \
    ../allegro`

Recebo este erro `CMake Error: Could not create named generator MSYS Makefiles`

Não encontrei nada na internet de como resolver este problema. Do que reparei os geradores que aparecem estão relacionados com os programas instalados, será que instalar o msys( primeira versão ) ajudará?

Já agora tenho também a instalar uns pacotes do tutorial como `mingw-w64-x86_64-dumb`e `mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf`. Mas de momento não são a minha prioridade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já achei solução para isto à muito tempo.

A solução é utilizar o shell do `mingw-w64` em vez do `msys2`.